# Sending DOM element from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dom, socket.io

I tried to clone a DOM object and send it to the server using socket.io and express, but after copying the element

( `const element = document.getElementById('id').cloneNode;` )
my server receives an empty object {}

and when i do `console.log(element);` on the client side everything works

(I send it into server by:

```
socket.on('document', (data, callback) => {
callback( document.getElementById(data[2]).cloneNode(true) );
})
```

Comment: Data should be serializable

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io converts objects to JSON to send over the wire. DOM elements have no properties that will convert to JSON.

```js
const body = JSON.stringify(document.body);
console.log(body);
```

You'll need to copy the values you care about into a new object and convert any non-JSON data types into something that JSON can represent.